# Проблема с composer

Tags: php, composer

Устанавливаю шаблон `yii2 kit start`. Пишу:

```
composer.phar install
```

и мне выдает ошибку:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages. Problem 1
>       - The requested PHP extension ext-intl * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.

Как устранить эту ошибку?

Comment: И в чём затруднения?

Comment: Я вроде бы написал)

Comment: В тексте ошибки сказано, что не  хватает расширения. Почему Вы его не установите?

Comment: Какая операционная система?